# Comment History in Sales Order Admin view

Tags: email-templates, order-status

When I review the Sales order it show specific steps in the processing of the order.  There are specific comments about the transactions that occurred during the processing of the order.
I like to be able to use them to display the transaction information on the customer Invoice or Sales Order confirmation.

I just not sure where this data is stored and how to retrieve it so it sill show on the Sales Order Invoice Confirmation?

Mar 28, 2017 2:25:46 PM|Processing
Customer  Notification Not Applicable
**Captured amount of $15.49 online. Transaction ID: "40038692970-capture". .**

Mar 28, 2017 2:25:46 PM|Processing
Customer  Not Notified
**Amount of $15.49 approved by payment gateway. Transaction ID: "40038692970". .**

Mar 28, 2017 2:25:46 PM|Processing
Customer  Not Notified
**This transaction has been approved.** .

---

I have example above.

Comment: Hmmm, really surprised I have not any comments?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually didn't understand your answer, this Answer applies only if you want to display Order comment to sales_order grid, this will show last comment to sales_order grid

As editing core files is not a good idea, You Have to copy files of `app\code\code\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\grid.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\grid.php` (Create the path if not exist)

After copying file to local look for `_prepareColumns()` function and add

```
    $this->addColumn('history', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Comment'),
        'type'  => 'text',
        'renderer' => new Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_History()
    ));
```

After adding this code to grid.php
Create a custom render( create path `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Renderer\History.php`)

inside History.php put this code

```
<?php class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_History extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $orderId = $row->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $history = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
        return $history->getComment();
    }
}
```

Your order comment should be on Sales_order grid now.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: If this Answers helps you please Accept this as an answer, So this Answer will help upcoming viewers.

Comment: Hi, how to filter these results in the grid?